# Как запустить асинхронно несколько запросов в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Значит, есть сервер. Он отдает поступившие сообщения.
Есть id аккаунтов для проверки.
И есть знания php, хорошие.

Что нужно. Нужно ОДНОВРЕМЕННО проверять сообщения для 10-20 аккаунтов.
То есть запустить типа асинхронные запросы по указанным http/htpps адресам и ждать ответа по тайм-ауту 30 секунд.
При получении ответа записывать инфу в бд mysql и снова делать запрос на сервер и так далее...

Как это сделать, посоветуйте, если на php трудно/плохо/геморно,
посоветуйте, на чем сделать, чтоб не шибко сложно. )

Работал недавно с phantomjs, может, как-то на нем? Или что там еще есть...

UPD

А можно сделать так: типа запустить скрипт столько раз, сколько аккаунтов, с параметрами акка? Или они все равно будут по очереди выполняться? Типа:

```
php get_mess.php akk=1 
php get_mess.php akk=2 
.....
```

но так, чтоб не ждать завершения первой запущеной задачи, а сразу запускать вторую и т.д.

Comment: По вашему update`у: можно запустить процессы в фоне. Например:

    php get_mess.php akk=1 > akk_1.log 2>$1 &
    php get_mess.php akk=2 > akk_2.log 2>$1 &
    ...
    php get_mess.php akk=N > akk_N.log 2>$1 &

Тогда запуск процессов хоть и будет последовательным, но выполняться они будут параллельно. [МАН](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)

Т.е. создали bash-скрипт с этим содержимым и по крону (или из другого скрипта) его запускаете когда надо

Answer (score 1):

Тут помогут вам *потоки* http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php
Но это довольно затратная процедура для PHP. Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону скриптов на других ЯП, например, Python.

**UPD**: Вот еще вдогонку *форки* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php.    Пользовались и тем, и тем. Надо смотреть на задачи и, исходя из этого, применять решение.
http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/ - *fork vs thread*

Comment: хорошо, а можете дать ссылку на примере питона, как на нем подобное реализуеться. Может, не оч. и сложно. Или не стесняйтесь, давайте ссылки, как реализовать на другом, т.к. я буду для этой штуки брать минимум вдс и поставлю туда, что надо,

Comment: > Но это довольно затратная процедура для PHP.

Как будто в других языках этот функционал принципиально иначе реализован. Да и форк наверняка сожрет куда больше ресурсов, чем реализация треда в текущем процессе.

Comment: Ну, чисто ради интереса завтра набросаю приложение с потоками на питоне, а сейчас вот несколько примеров:

1. http://habrahabr.ru/post/78267/
2. http://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/

Ну, единственное, что обработку в потоках надо писать уже такую, какая нужна вам.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, вроде как cURL умеет многопоток [линк](http://habrahabr.ru/post/68175/).

Но как и писали выше, подобное лучше делать не на php (напр., на python).

По опыту скажу, что такие скрипты прожорливы, но в меру. Сам писал реализацию подобного механизма на питоне, запускается ежеменутно и в 50 потоков делает в среднем по 50-55 запросов (т. е. примерно по 1 запросу в потоке) и при этом жрет стабильно 3+-1,5% на самом дешевом сервере на [DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Можете сделать так: один скрипт работает как монитор - запускает, например, 6 скриптов одновременно и по крону следит - если скрипты "упали", перезапускает их.
2. Посмотрите в сторону сервера очередей. Например [rabbitMq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Под него есть очень удобная библиотека на php.